# determinants and invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, let

$\det(\lambda I_n - A) = \lambda ^n + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k\lambda^k$

denote the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Prove that if $A$ is invertible, then
$$
A^{-1} = \frac{-1}{a_0}\left[A^{n-1} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} a_kA^{k-1}\right]
$$
Please help, I have no idea.

Comment: This tells how to write $A^{-1}$ in terms of $A$ when $A$ is invertible

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  A matrix always satisfies its characteristic polynomial.

Comment: I'm having a hard time just working through the notation. I've been out of any sort of mathematical education for 14 years and now have to take a graduate level linear algebra class. Could someone help me understand what is being asked. Maybe lay it out in a way that doesn't use so much notation.